# byte[] to image conversion spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, stream

I need clarification with byte[] to image conversion in spring boot, according to the following code I could get the image but, it could not display. so I need the solution to display the image while I calling the API,
http://localhost:9000/files/d317447b-7235-47c5-9923-bc65aae89d76

```
@GetMapping("/files/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getFile(@PathVariable String id) {
        FileDB fileDB = storageService.getFile(id);
        log.info("{}->{}","FILES_GET_BY_ID:",id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileDB.getName() + "\"")
                .body(fileDB.getData());
    }
```

Finally I got the solution.

```
@GetMapping("/files/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getFile(@PathVariable String id) {
        FileDB fileDB = storageService.getFile(id);
        log.info("{}->{}","FILES_GET_BY_ID:",id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileDB.getName() + "\"")
                .body(fileDB.getData());
    }
```

Comment: If you want to show the image using an `<img` tag just stream the `byte[]`. You are currently preparing things for a file download.

Comment: I wanna use url instead of byte[]

Comment: No you don't. A URL is just ap ointer to something just stream the byte[] and make sure you set the content-type correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the HTTP header
instead of using ACCEPT use the header Content-Disposition
also set the response type to relevant one.

Comment: before I tried that but, the file could download; but, I need to show the image

Comment: remove attachment and set filename in content-deposition
attachment will force browser to download